Execute Geometry Nodes tool from Python
Let's say I have a simple geonodes tool:

How do I execute it from Python, specifying "X" (socket_2)?
I know I could add and apply a geonodes modifier, but that requires object mode and the modifier won't have access to read/write "Selection"...

Geometry Nodes can process only Object mode mesh, not an Edit mode one, so you have to switch to Object mode in any case. And in case you in object mode then you can just add modifer to object and apply..

@modnop interesting,  so when I run the tool in edit mode it switches to object mode and back? Why can I choose both edit and object in geotool options? Also I would need to use numpy to transfer selection to a custom attribute...

Since Mesh and BMesh completely different thing.. its just more easier to convert one to other one than actually support such real time reflection. Even in case this is real time conversion for viewport display.
